# convert mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm PM to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql-server

im busy with temp db's

5/2/2018 1:01 pm has 8 strings to get to the end of "2018"
4/20/2018 1:01 pm has 9 and
12/20/2018 1:01 pm has 10

so how the hell will this query work:

`UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [Date Only] = SUBSTRING([TSQCApproved],1,10)
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [Time Only] =SUBSTRING([TSQCApproved],12,8) PRINT`

If I choose the top code, it returns part of the time in the date column.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using invalid standard SQL in your question). Please add a tag for the database product you are using

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated tag. I'm using SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CHARINDEX()` function instead of passing *static* length :

```
UPDATE #OutstandingClean 
SET [Date Only] = SUBSTRING([TSQCApproved], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [TSQCApproved]));
```

This assumes *SQL Server* Database Engine, since you haven't tagged the DBMS.

Comment: **Thank You**  Worked well